# Application Insights add http filter

Tags: java, web-applications, apache-camel

so I am running a java web app using application insights and am having trouble adding an http filter.  I am using Apache Camel and have so far been unsuccessful.  This project does not have a web.xml file.  How do you add an http filter in apache camel?  Here is what I have tried so far:

```
from("some http client")

        .beanRef("foo", "myMethod")
        .beanRef("foo", "myMethod")
        .filter().method("com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.WebRequestTrackingFilter", "doFilter");
        .choice()

        .when(isGET).process(someProcessor)
          .when(isPUT).process(someProcessor)
          .when(isPOST).process(someProcessor)
          .when(isDELETE).process(someProcessor)
          .otherwise().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(404));
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the content of WebRequestTrackingFilter ? What content you are trying to filter that might need implementing a custom filter?

Comment: WebRequestTrackingFilter contains doFilter() that takes a servlet request, servlet response, and a filter chain.  It returns a void.  I am trying to track server response times, server requests, and failure requests.  I have made custom events for site navigation and other things.  Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.  Had to create a wrapper and used

```
.filter().method("Class", "doFilter")
```

doFilter() takes a request, response, and chain that you can get from Camel.